# how to add multiple values from checkbox into .txt file

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

For a simple voting system, i put the values into a .txt file.
This is the array i use:

```
$quickpolloptions = ['Mozilla', 'Chrome', 'Opera', 'IE', 'Safari'];
```

This is the form:

```
<form method="post" id="quickpoll">
   foreach ($quickpolloptions as $key => $value) {
         echo "<tr>";
             echo "<td>";
                    echo "<label>$value</label>";
         echo "</td>";
         echo "<td>";
                    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkboxvote[]' value='$key'><br>";
         echo "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is how i store the data:

```
$result_file = "data/vote_result.txt";

if (file_exists($result_file)) {
   $results = explode(',', file_get_contents('data/vote_result.txt'));
} else {
   // start with zeros if you don't have a file yet
   $results = array_fill(0, count($quickpolloptions), 0);
}

// below i am trying to read each value fromn checkbox and store in .txt file

if (isset($_POST['checkboxvote'])) {

  foreach ($_POST['checkboxvote'] as $checkbox) {
    $results[$_POST['checkboxvote']]++;
    file_put_contents('data/vote_result.txt', implode(',', $results));
  }
}
```

So i do not succeed in the last part: to put multiple values in the txt file.

How can i do that?

Comment: `$_POST['checkboxvote']` is an array. Array as a key is not what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `$checkbox` variable as the key to `$results` when incrementing the values. Also, don't write to the file inside the loop. Just update the array and then write to the file once.

```
if (isset($_POST['checkboxvote'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['checkboxvote'] as $checkbox) {
        $results[$checkbox]++;
    }
    file_put_contents('data/vote_result.txt', implode(',', $results));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `$results[$_POST['checkboxvote']]++;` should be `$results[$checkbox]++;`

Note that your implementation is susceptible to race conditions if two people vote at the same time.

You should use file locks or consider an RDBMS with transaction protection.

**Example:**

```
if (isset($_POST['checkboxvote'])) {

  /* lock the file to prevent a race condition */
  $file_handle = fopen($result_file, 'a+');
  $locked = flock($file_handle, LOCK_EX);

  /* retrieve the results now that we are locked */
  $results = fgets($file_handle);
  if ($results !== false) {
    $results = explode(',', $results);
  } else {
    $results = array_fill(0, count($quickpolloptions), 0);
  }

  /* update the results */
  foreach ($_POST['checkboxvote'] as $checkbox) {
    $results[$checkbox]]++;
  }

  /* write them to the file and unlock */
  ftruncate($file_handle, 0);
  fputs($file_handle, implode(',', $results));
  flock($file_handle, LOCK_UN);
  fclose($file_handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your foreach loop you are looping over `$_POST['checkboxvote']` which is correct. However `$checkbox` is the element.

Second, you are inserting the value into the index of `$results`, you need them as the data of the results so implode will combine them.

Lastly, you should call `file_put_contents()` outside of your foreach loop. If you call it multiple times it will appear to work correctly but it will be wasting time by overwriting your file each loop.

```
foreach ($_POST['checkboxvote'] as $checkbox) {
  $results[] = $checkbox;
  file_put_contents('data/vote_result.txt', implode(',', $results));
}
```

or

```
foreach ($_POST['checkboxvote'] as $key => $checkbox) {
  $results[] = $_POST['checkboxvote'][$key];
  file_put_contents('data/vote_result.txt', implode(',', $results));
}
```

Comment: I don't think either of these will work because HTML does not submit checkboxes that are not checked, but I agree file_put_contents should be outside of the loop for sure.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming the second code block is an HTTP endpoint which you hit to save data into your `vote_result.txt` file.

You're getting the contents of what's currently in that file right now and assigning it to the variable `$result` - something which you don't need to do since you never actually return it as a response from the script.

All you need is the code that will take the POST parameter array of `checkboxvote` and save it as a string with commas separating the values.  Something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['checkboxvote'])){
    file_put_contents('data/vote_result.txt', implode(',', $_POST['checkboxvote']));
}
```

You don't need the for loop when writing to your file since `implode()` already breaks down your array into one string.

Now, when you POST to your script with the following parameter:

```
checkboxvote[]='owl'
checkboxvote[]='chicken'
checkboxvote[]='deer'
```

Your `vote_result.txt` will look like:

```
owl,chicken,deer
```

Comment: This won't work, it doesn't increment his counts, for example 3 people voted for 'owl', 2 people for 'deer'.

Comment: @BrandonHorsley `implode()` turns the array into a string.  You shouldn't be running through the array when you already have all the values in string format.

Comment: I understand what `implode` does, but he is looking to keep a running count of how many people voted for each option.  This solution only stores the last persons vote.

Comment: @BrandonHorsley He doesn't mention anything related to submitting to the endpoint to count votes from multiple people.  In fact, it's not even a vote system, he's keeping count of what was selected in multiple check boxes by one person.

Comment: @BrandonHorsley Look at his code, it is obviously not a voting system.  I doubt English was the OP's first language so he may have trouble expressing his question.  You should brush up on your English comprehension too